# Alternator going out or Power steering.....?

Tags: honda, alternator, stall, power-steering, rough-idle

Got a 2009 Honda Accord that's been idling a little rough and shuddering/vibrating. When I turn the steering wheel, RPMs quickly jump from 500 - 1100 and then quick drop down and car sputters like it will stall then returns to normal.

Only happens when stationary or when I come to a stop at a light. Had alternator checked and they told me it barely passed and has 12.5 - 13V output. I also noticed it takes 3 seconds from turning the key to the engine starting. Battery is new and was putting out 12V. Any test I can do to isolate? I don't want to just throw parts at it.

Comment: Since both the PS pump and the alternator are driven from the same belt, have you checked the serpentine belt and tensioner?  It's possible the belt is failing or the tensioner is not working right.

Comment: Can the cause the car to feel like it will stall?